# Unable to register device to azure notification hub using nodejs packages

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

We are trying to send push notification dynamically to all registered devices (**android**) using azure push notification. when we are trying to register the device using device token received from flutter mobile app. it is not getting registered.

**For reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-nodejs-push-notification-tutorial

In the above documentation, there is no step to register device using their device token to notification hub. So tried to check on some tech forums and got a sample way to proceed on registering device. Code is below for reference.

```
    notificationHubService.gcm.createTemplateRegistration(
'replacing device token',
'tag', {
'aps': {
'alert': '$(message)',
'badge': '#(count)',
'sound': 'default'
}
},
function (e, r) {
if (e) {
console.log(e);
} else {
console.log({
id: r.RegistrationId,
deviceToken: r.DeviceToken,
expires: r.ExpirationTime
});
}
}
);
```

**Response**

{
id: '1294571364808236565-5460521645299605787-1',
deviceToken: undefined,
expires: '9999-12-31T23:59:59.999'
}

device token is always returning as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this sample of how to use the Azure-SB SDK [here](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmpodwysocki%2Fazure-notificationhubs-node-sample%2Fblob%2Fmain%2Fsrc%2Findex.ts%23L19&data=04%7C01%7Cbrtrach%40microsoft.com%7C5d661bb00a9e45df110908d8e8cb4949%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637515307103462564%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=ey%2FvjYzleoQDskG0wbO0E3OiKoLyuEevnFAYcxG6NFk%3D&reserved=0).

Using this example, you can set the GCM_REGISTRATION_ID which is the device token from the Android device such as you would get from [here](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fandroid%2Fclient%23retrieve-the-current-registration-token&data=04%7C01%7Cbrtrach%40microsoft.com%7C5d661bb00a9e45df110908d8e8cb4949%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637515307103472519%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=EXvQvw1UoTa%2BfCfeNb8pRlVYGDFco8fna%2BoLF0J9WAM%3D&reserved=0).

This has the usage of GCM/Firebase here in registering, which is using the REST-API method of create registration under the covers: [Create a registration | Microsoft Docs](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Frest%2Fapi%2Fnotificationhubs%2Fcreate-registration&data=04%7C01%7Cbrtrach%40microsoft.com%7C5d661bb00a9e45df110908d8e8cb4949%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637515307103472519%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=OuVtAVQ84qFQqiEtT4sRAC33AVE5rytgebehtzPmd1w%3D&reserved=0)

Comment: Facing error on consoling the response

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>) @Bryan

Comment: followed this code structure and passed device token as registration id
service.gcm.createNativeRegistration(GCM_REGISTRATION_ID, SAMPLE_TAG, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }

    console.log('Registration success');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));

    service.gcm.send(SAMPLE_TAG, GCM_MESSAGE, (error, res) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
      }

      console.log('Message sent');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
    });
  });

Comment: Also if getting registered how can we check the registered device inside azure portal ? @bryan